# Rails 3.2 and has_one when reference key does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

below worked in Rails 3.0.x, does not in 3.2

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :phone_number

  has_one :zipcode, :primary_key => :area_code_id, :foreign_key => :area_code

  def area_code_id
    phone_number[0..2]
  end
end
```

When I call:

```
 - Phone.first.zipcode
```

Query is always:

```
 - SELECT "zipcodes".* FROM "zipcodes" WHERE "zipcodes"."area_code" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

------- EDIT -------

```
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area_code, :city, :zip_code

  has_many :phones, :finder_sql => Proc.new {"SELECT DISTINCT phones.* FROM phones WHERE '#{area_code}' = substr(phones.phone_number, 1,3);"}

end
```

------ POSSIBLE WORKAROUND FOR SOME ---------

As Michael pointed out, on new version of rails it expects the reference key in DB.

So A possible workaround

```
Phone.select("phones.*, "substring(phones.area_code, 1, 3) as area_code_id").first.zipcode
```

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: Please show all the code for your Phone model, There might be a default scope there.

Comment: Where is the has_one association?

Comment: Sorry, trying to change associations to see where its failing. Added column in table and it worked.  But cannot add this table in production db.

Comment: If you're saying that the primary key in the zipcodes table is area_code_id then shouldn't the query say "WHERE zipcodes.area_code_id = x"? Also, could the IS NULL be because your first phones record happens to have a null zipcode foreign key?

Comment: Primary key to use from the Phone model is area_code_id and foreign Key in the Zipcode table is area_code.

Comment: updated question with model from Zipcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if it is possible to change the models, you should have/use an id field (called `id`) with no "business meaning" at all, e.g. not a phone number or area code or anything like that.

Then you can remove the `primary_key` setting.

Then add validations on that specific field for uniqueness etc.

I know it's a pain that it worked in one rails version and not another but the correct route to make this work going into the future is probably the above.  Rails really depends on you following the conventions unless you really know its inner workings in detail to override them.

Comment: Michael, you are right.  On new versions of Rails, key is taken from sql response.  I updated question with possible solution for some situations.

Answer (score 0):

seems, the only way is to define association manually.

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :phone_number

  def zipcode
    Zipcode.where(:area_code => area_code_id)
  end

  def area_code_id
    phone_number[0..2]
  end

end
```

Comment: Although yes this would work, would like to avoid it.  Reason = In some of my reports views would have to work with @ 100 + Phones which would result in 100+ zipcode queries.